# CMake: setting a linker flag on a static library, to be used by the consumer when linking (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, cmake

I have the following situation: a static library `MyStaticLib` depending on several libraries of the FFmpeg project (`libavformat` etc.).

The FFmpeg libraries were linked (not by me) with the "/SAFESEH:NO" option, which means that any image that links to them (via their import libraries) must also be linked with the same option (failure to do so makes the linker abort with "LNK2026: module unsafe for SAFESEH image").

I've tried everything I could think of, but I haven't found a way to attach that option to my `MyStaticLib` in a way that would make it propagate to the consumer.

This seems strange, because CMake does provide the means for *compiler* options to propagate to consumers: the command `target_compile_options()` used with the `PUBLIC` option does exactly that.

Is there no similar feature for linker flags?

Comment: According to this [mail](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-August/058198.html), it was intended to use `target_link_libraries(MyStaticLib INTERFACE "/SAFESEH:NO")` for propagate linker flags, or directly set `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property. But CMake incorrectly works with '/' symbol in that property: it assume the property to be a path on Windows, and replace '/' with '\'.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, this confirms what I thought. Do you know if the CMake maintainers are aware of this?

Comment: I don't know. Searching cmake [bugtracker](https://cmake.org/Bug) with "windows slash" hasn't found any issue related to given problem. So, you can fill one. Possible solition for cmake may be replacing character '/' to '\' *only when it is non-first*. As I know, unlike to UNIX-like systems, string `\bla-bla-bla` cannot denote path on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

VC++ [compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx) and [linker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx5b050y.aspx) accept both
a forward slash (/) and a dash (–) as an option specifier.
As [mentioned by @tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290879/cmake-setting-a-linker-flag-on-a-static-library-to-be-used-by-the-consumer-whe/37204841#comment54385122_33290879), CMake may have problems with forward slash, treating it as a path separator.
Therefore you need to use the following command to add a linker option to MyStaticLib target and propagate the option to the MyStaticLib consumers:

```
target_link_libraries(MyStaticLib PUBLIC "-SAFESEH:NO")
```

or if your build config supports other compilers as well:

```
target_link_libraries(MyStaticLib PUBLIC "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:-SAFESEH:NO>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with CMake 3.13, you need to use `target_link_options()` instead:

```
target_link_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:-SAFESEH:NO>")
```

Tested with CMake 3.16.2 and MSVC2019.

Comment: As per [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.23/command/target_link_options.html), `target_link_options()` is just an alternative to `target_link_libraries()`, it is **not** a recommended replacement. Also note that `target_link_options()` "_cannot be used to add options for static library targets, since they do not use a linker_".